# Не могу сделать отступы для .select() в JQuery UI

Tags: css, jquery, jquery-ui

Добавил в html тэг `select` с классом `meal`, после чего используя библиотеку JQuery UI я стилизовал `meal` через `.selectmenu()`, сейчас мне необходимо подвинуть этот `meal` вправо на n кол-во пикселов, но используюя `margin`/`padding` он не двигается, постоянно прижат к левому краю. Я подозреваю, что проблема в "корневых" стилях JQuery UI, но самостоятельно не могу решить эту проблему.
[image: На фото, то как выглядит данная ситуация на странице. Красная стрелочка - сам <code>meal</code>, а красный прямоугольник - то место где он должен быть.]

На фото, то как выглядит данная ситуация на странице. Красная стрелочка - сам  `meal`, а красный прямоугольник - то место где он должен быть. 
Буду благодарен за помощь. Сам проект и код вы можете посмотреть [тут](https://catinears.github.io/RepeatPaymentsForm/)

---

UPD: Правильный ответ в комментариях дал [meine](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/321863/meine): `radioContainer - margin-right: npx`

Comment: `radioContainer - margin-right: npx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ в комментариях дал meine:

```
radioContainer - margin-right: npx
```

Answer (score 0):

> Я подозреваю, что проблема в "корневых" стилях JQuery UI, но
>   самостоятельно не могу решить эту проблему.

Добавьте в своих стилях, в конце: **!important**

Например:

```
margin-right: 1px !important;
```